Issue with importing .xlsx into Pandas
I´m trying to import a Dataframe from an .xlsx with double header column. However when the .xlsx file contains 2 rows to skip the first header column is not read correctly.
import pandas as pd
#Python 3.12.7
#pandas 2.2.2
#openpyxl 3.1.5

df = pd.read_excel('2_rows_to_skip.xlsx', skiprows=[0,1], header=[0,1])
df2 = pd.read_excel('1_row_to_skip.xlsx', skiprows=[0], header=[0,1])
   
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
    
print('-------------------')

for col in df2.columns:
    print(col)

The prints result in:
('header1', 'A')
('Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'B')
('Unnamed: 2_level_0', 'C')
('header2', 'A')
('Unnamed: 4_level_0', 'B')
('Unnamed: 5_level_0', 'C')
-------------------
('header1', 'A')
('header1', 'B')
('header1', 'C')
('header2', 'A')
('header2', 'B')
('header2', 'C')

In the file where 2 rows need to be skipped the first header column row is not read correctly, by not assigning header1 to the second and third column, and header2 to the 5 and 6. column. However the same dataframe in a .xlsx file with one row to skip works fine.
Any idea what causes this issue?
.xlsx files are uploaded in here

A possible solution for the second excel file:
df = pd.read_excel('2_rows_to_skip.xlsx', skiprows=2, header=[0,1])

Output:
  header1       header2      
        A  B  C       A  B  C
0       1  3  5       6  7  8
1       2  4  5       6  7  8
2       4  5  6       7  8  9


A possible solution for the first excel file:
df = pd.read_excel('1_row_to_skip.xlsx', skiprows=1, header=[0,1])

Output:
  header1       header2      
        A  B  C       A  B  C
0       1  3  5       6  7  8
1       2  4  5       6  7  8
2       4  5  6       7  8  9

